# Mpdf Barcode size is too big. want to fix height and width

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to create barcode using mpdf. while creating, its automatically changing height and width. Please give me solution to fix height and width even though characters are different.

```
<barcode code="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234" type="C39E+" 
class="barcode" size="3" height="3" />
```

want to generate 5 barcodes on a page with equal space.

page size 50*100mm.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour and get to know how this site works. Post some code. Show some efforts, what you have tried so far.

Comment: below is the example. code not more than 30 characters. but it may vary to 5 to 30.
<barcode code="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234" type="C39E+" class="barcode" size="2" height="2" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mpdf documentation and examples provided when you download the scripts from their website: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download

If you have a look at their barcode example example37_barcodes.php (examples/example37_barcodes.php), if you want to modify the size for the C39E+ barcode type you will have to do this:

> These barcodes are all of variable length depending on the code entered. There is no recommended maximum size for any of these specs, but all recommend a minimum X-dimension (width of narrowest bar) as 7.5mil (=0.19mm). The default used here is twice the minimum i.e. X-dim = 0.38mm.
>
> The specifications give a minimum height of 15% of the barcode length (which can be variable). The bar height in mPDF is set to a default value of 10mm. 'size' will scale the barcode in both dimensions. mPDF will accept any number, but bear in mind that size="0.5" will set the bar width to the minimum. The 'height' attribute further allows scaling - this factor is applied to already scaled barcode. Thus size="2" height="0.5" will give a barcode twice the default width (X-dim=0.76mm) and at the default height set in mPDF i.e. 10mm.

The results may vary according to the value passed to the barcode class, so I think if you want a fixed width and height you should try an external library that creates an barcode image file with the desired size or forcing the barcode to adjust to a fixed row or div in a table.

I had the same problem and tried the following using an external library passing values to a function:

```
$codigoBarras = "<img src='barcode/script/html/image.php?code=code128&o=1&t=12&r=1&text=$productoID&f1=Arial.ttf&f2=0&a1=A&a2=' width='110' height='25'>";
```

image.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['t']) && isset($_GET['r']) && isset($_GET['text']) && isset($_GET['f1']) && isset($_GET['f2']) && isset($_GET['o']) && isset($_GET['a1']) && isset($_GET['a2'])){
    define('IN_CB',true);
    require('config.php');
    require($class_dir.'/index.php');
    require($class_dir.'/FColor.php');
    require($class_dir.'/BarCode.php');
    require($class_dir.'/FDrawing.php');
    require($class_dir.'/Font.php');
    if(include($class_dir.'/'.$_GET['code'].'.barcode.php')){
        if($_GET['f1'] !== '0' && intval($_GET['f2']) >= 1){
            $font = new Font($class_dir.'/font/'.$_GET['f1'], intval($_GET['f2']));
        } else {
            $font = 0;
        }
        $color_black = new FColor(0,0,0);
        $color_white = new FColor(255,255,255);
        if(!empty($_GET['a2']))
            $code_generated =& new $_GET['code']($_GET['t'],$color_black,$color_white,$_GET['r'],$_GET['text'],$font,$_GET['a1'],$_GET['a2']);
        elseif(!empty($_GET['a1']))
            $code_generated =& new $_GET['code']($_GET['t'],$color_black,$color_white,$_GET['r'],$_GET['text'],$font,$_GET['a1']);
        else
            $code_generated =& new $_GET['code']($_GET['t'],$color_black,$color_white,$_GET['r'],$_GET['text'],$font);
        $drawing =& new FDrawing('',$color_white);
        $drawing->add_barcode($code_generated);
        $drawing->draw_all();
        $drawing->finish(intval($_GET['o']));
    }
    else{
        header('Content: image/png');
        readfile('error.png');
    }
}
else{
    header('Content: image/png');
    readfile('error.png');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<barcode type="EAN13" code="978-0-9542246-0" text="0" class="barcode" size="1" height="0.5"/>
```

always size ='1'